# || not working in if else C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm building a simple menu that the user can select from. For some reason

```
else if (letterSelect == "C" || letterSelect = "c")
```

The || is coming up with an error. The other || work fine. The error is: no operator "||" matches these operand. operand types are; bool || std::string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{


cout << "********* General Purpose Calculator Program ***************\n"
    << "Please Select an Option by inputting its associated letter\n"
    << "A)  Determine Highest of Three Numbers\n"
    << "B) Reverse a Number\n"
    << "C)Calculate Parking Garage Charges\n"
    << "D) Exit\n";

string letterSelect = " ";


cin >> letterSelect;

if (letterSelect == "A" || letterSelect == "a")

{

    //call program listed for A;

}

else if (letterSelect == "B" || letterSelect == "b")

{

    //call program listed for B;

}

else if (letterSelect == "C" || letterSelect = "c")

{

    //call program listed for C;

}

else (letterSelect == "D" || letterSelect == "d");


    cout << "Exiting...";


}
```

Comment: letterSelect = "c" should be letterSelect == "c"

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
else if (letterSelect == "C" || letterSelect = "c")
```

You are missing `=` in second part of condition.
It should be `letterSelect == "c"`

Answer (score 1):

Just a typo.
The right-hand side of the '||' in your code is an assignment (=), not an equality check (==).

Answer (score 1):

The line of code

```
letterSelect = "c"
```

Is an assignment operation instead of a comparison. Change it to

```
letterSelect == "c"
```

And it should work.

Happy coding.